# How to design multiple screens on the same device, same size

Tags: android, screen

Just started with Android programming. Working on a scoreboard for a card game for my 10 inch tablet. I'm not looking for screen set up for different sizes, but working with different screens(views) on the same device. My screen has 4 parts with each a number of views (textview, button):

In the left top is "part A". On the right of Part A is part B. Under part A is part C and right from part C is part D.

All parts are visible all the time. The views of part A,B,C remain the same, but part D should show sometimes 2gridview/textview and sometimes a textview and a button, depending on what button is pressed on part A.

How do I define this in XML and how to show the changed part D button/texview ? Do the definitions need to be in different XML files ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be a proper and clean solution for your needs:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

You might find it very handy and dynamic once you learn it. (I learnt it in a few days by myself...)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look there first.